# Cannot find module with yarn workspaces for Angular & React apps in monorepo

Tags: reactjs, angular, yarn-workspaces, yarn-v2

We just started up a new project and decided to do it in monorepo together with the existing one. The existing project is in Angular 10 with some parts in React. The new project is purely React.

It seems like everything is getting installed properly and even all the tests are passing. However, when I try to build or even run the application (for the old project) I am getting the following error:

```
~/PRIZ/dev/priz-fe/platform (PRZ-140) $ yarn run build --delete-output-path
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:818
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/shurikag/PRIZ/dev/priz-fe/platform/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

I feel like it is something dumb that I am missing. Also, the IDE is not complaining about anything.

The folder structure looks like this:
[image]

Root package.json:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "name": "priz-fe",
  "workspaces": [
    "platform",
    "hub"
  ],
  "packageManager": "yarn@3.1.1"
}
```

Platform package.json:

```
{
  "name": "platform",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "start-with-ssl": "node --max-old-space-size=4096 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve --ssl --ssl-key docker/ssl/server.key --ssl-cert docker/ssl/server.pem",
    "build": "node --max-old-space-size=4096 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --configuration=production",
    "test": "jest --maxConcurrency=2 --maxWorkers=2",
    "update-snapshots": "jest --updateSnapshot",
    "test-with-coverage": "ng test --code-coverage",
    "eslint": "eslint 'src/app/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'",
    "eslint:fix": "eslint --fix 'src/app/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'",
    "lint": "yarn run eslint",
    "tsc": "tsc --skipLibCheck --noEmit",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -s public -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook",
    "fmt": "prettier --write --config ./.prettierrc.yml '*.{js,yml}' 'src/app/**/*.{js,ts,tsx,scss,component.html}'",
    "fmt:check": "prettier --config ./.prettierrc.yml --check '*.{js,yml}' 'src/app/**/*.{js,ts,tsx,scss,component.html}'",
    "check": "yarn run fmt:check && yarn run tsc && yarn run lint",
    "pre-commit": "yarn run fmt && yarn run check && yarn run test"
  },
  "jest": {
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest",
      "^.+\\.svg$": "jest-svg-transformer"
    },
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(css|less)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "setupFiles": [
      "jest-canvas-mock"
    ]
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-redux/store": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^12.2.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "^12.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^12.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "^12.2.5",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^9.0.0-beta.29",
    "@angular/forms": "^12.2.5",
    "@angular/material": "^12.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^12.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^12.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "^12.2.5",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "@date-io/date-fns": "1.3.13",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.6.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.28",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.14",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.60",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.3.10",
    "@sentry/browser": "^5.15.5",
    "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.5.0",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.19.1",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.39",
    "angular-i18next": "^10.1.0",
    "auth0-js": "^9.14.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "date-fns": "^2.23.0",
    "flux-standard-action": "^2.0.3",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "html-react-parser": "^1.2.6",
    "i18next": "^20.2.1",
    "i18next-http-backend": "^1.2.1",
    "jest-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
    "keycharm": "^0.4.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "mixpanel-browser": "^2.28.0",
    "ngx-logger": "^4.1.9",
    "ngx-mat-select-search": "^3.1.2",
    "ngx-quill": "^13.0.1",
    "object-hash": "^2.0.3",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "quill-image-compress": "^1.2.16",
    "quill-image-resize-module-react": "^3.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-avatar-editor": "^12.0.0",
    "react-color": "^2.19.3",
    "react-colorful": "^5.1.4",
    "react-currency-format": "^1.0.0",
    "react-dnd": "^14.0.4",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^14.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.15.2",
    "react-i18next": "^11.8.13",
    "react-keyed-flatten-children": "^1.3.0",
    "react-player": "^2.9.0",
    "react-query": "^3.13.6",
    "react-quill": "^1.3.5",
    "react-redux": "7.2.2",
    "react-select": "^4.3.1",
    "reduce-reducers": "^1.0.4",
    "redux": "4.0.1",
    "redux-actions": "^2.6.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "reselect": "^4.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.5",
    "sass": "^1.39.0",
    "svg-react-loader": "^0.4.6",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.1",
    "vis-data": "^7.1.2",
    "vis-network": "^9.0.4",
    "vis-util": "^5.0.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1002.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^12.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^12.2.5",
    "@angular/language-service": "^12.2.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.5",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.1.11",
    "@storybook/addon-controls": "^6.1.11",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.1.11",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.1.11",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.1.11",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.6",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
    "@types/mixpanel-browser": "^2.23.1",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.26.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.26.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.2",
    "eslint": "^7.28.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^5.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.23.4",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.3.6",
    "eslint-plugin-jest-dom": "^3.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.24.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-testing-library": "^4.6.0",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-canvas-mock": "^2.3.1",
    "msw": "^0.35.0",
    "msw-storybook-addon": "^1.3.0",
    "prettier": "^2.3.1",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.2",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.4",
    "ts-jest": "^26.5.6",
    "ts-node": "~8.0.1",
    "typescript": "4.3.5",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.4.0"
  },
  "msw": {
    "workerDirectory": "public"
  },
  "workspaces": {
    "nohoist": [
      "**"
    ]
  }
}
```